# How can I have two implementations(test and actual) of same class in SpringBoot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, environment-variables

I want to have two classes that implement the same interface but one should be used when tests are run and one should execute when the actual code is run. This should be based on the environment. So, if the environment is "CI" the test implementation should be used and if the environment is "development" or "production" the actual implementation should be used. How can this be achieved using SpringBoot and by following the best practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it would be to load your class as a component, based on condition.

1.You can make use of **Spring profile**.

```
@Profile("Cl")
```

This will load the required class accordingly based on the spring profile active.

In application.properties

```
spring.profiles.active=CL
```

Sample Code:

```
public interface Sample {
    void runData();
}


@Component
@Profile("CL")
public class TestSample implements Sample {
    
    @Override
    public void runData(){
        // your code
    }
}
```

Similarly you can set profile for other class which is required in Dev

2.You can also make use of `@ConditionalOnProperty(name="propertyname" , havingValue="true")`

You can control it by setting "propertyname" in application.properties file for the respective environment

application.properties

```
propertyname=true
```

Sample Code:

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="propertyname" , havingValue="true")
public class TestSample implements Sample {
    
    @Override
    public void runData(){
        // your code
    }
}
```